# Dice? = Is that so?

Tags: meaning

I have heard the following dialogue between a politician and a gangster in a TV series:

- G: Lei è un vero rappresentante del popolo.
- P: Esatto. Solo che non rappresento quelli come lei.
- G: Dice? Penso che io posso anche averla votata.
- P: Lo escludo.

What does "dice" mean here? "Is that so" ? Is it an usual expression?

Comment: I have answered about _dice_, but there is something amiss elsewhere. The first sentence doesn't really work. It should be either “Non rappresento persone come lei” or “Non rappresento quelli come lei” or, in a rather involute way, “Non rappresento persone di quelle come lei”. And after “Dice?” it probably is “Pensi che...”

Comment: @DaG I had (incorrectly) changed that first line in order to shorten the copied dialogue. I have fixed it now.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is. It literally means “Do you say (so)?” or, as you say, “Is that so?” or “Are you sure?”.

*Dice* is here the 3rd person singular of the present tense of *dire*. It's the 3rd person and not the 2nd since the two are using the courtesy form, *Lei*.